# Checking process is loaded

Tags: c#

Is there a way to check if an application has finished loading.

For example if I were to use `Process newProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\someFile.xls");`
is there `IsLoaded or IsFinishedLoading` or something similar to that, so that another line of code does not fire until the application is fully loaded.

I ask because I get an error when trying to interface with an excel sheet because its not open. Using only `Process newProcess = Process.Start(@"C:\someFile.xls");` does the job but only after my application has crashed due to no excel document being open.

Now is there a way to speed up the starting of the program/file? Or have I coded something incorrectly.

Comment: How is it you are interfacing? Through Interop/VSTO? In that case you wouldn't really open Excel through Process.Start, but create an Excel application instead and load the document.

Comment: I am using interop to access the excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no generic way to know when an application started or finished opening a document.

Some programs (i.e. Office applications) provide API to communicate/control them, while others (i.e. Notepad) have no way to know this information.

Comment: you reall should use the Microsoft Office SDK if you are trying to automate Office.  anything else will just be painful.  the office sdk will still be painful... but not as much.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to check whether an application has loaded the document? In that case is there a way to solve the problem I am having with the excel doc not loading until after my application crashes due to no excel to process.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using Interop, why not actually create the Excel Application, and load the document?
You can also make the application visible to the user as well, if you need to.

using:

```
Excel.Application excel = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
Workbook wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path, <parameters>);
```

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it, I have just decided to load it earlier on in the application for now.