# Waiting for another process window is fully loaded

Tags: c#, process, devexpress, wait

I was wondering how can I get to know if another application which I launch from Process.Start() is fully loaded (all controls are ready etc.), because WaitForInputIdle seems to be not working... In my case I need to create Automation Elements tree, but some DevExpress apps create controls dynamically and I have no clue how to check its state. I'm also checking the window with WindowPattern and WindowInteractionState, but it doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it depends on the application. Some include flags or methods of communication that will tell you this, while others do not.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304709/checking-process-is-loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether you are using DevExpress expressAppFramework, but in my experience of XAF 12.1 and later, there is a function `xafHasPendingCallbacks()`. If you can find a way of querying this function, you should be able to verify whether the DevExpress callbacks are complete.

For instance, with Selenium I use

```
function waitForCallbacks() {
    selenium.waitForCondition("typeof selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().xafHasPendingCallbacks == 'function';", timeout);
    selenium.waitForCondition("selenium.browserbot.getUserWindow().xafHasPendingCallbacks() == false;", timeout);
}
```

If you're using plain DevExpress controls (without XAF), then I don't think this approach will work, but if you can modify the page scripts, perhaps you could create a similar function.